# the trait `std::convert::From<rusqlite::Error>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`

Tags: rust, actix-web, rusqlite

I've tried replacing `Result<()>` with `Result<(), std::io::Error>` But it results in: more errors.

Error:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::io::Error`
  --> src/main.rs:48:53
   |
48 |     let conn = rusqlite::Connection::open("data.db")?;
   |                                                     ^ the trait `std::convert::From<rusqlite::Error>` is not implemented for `std::io::Error`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`:
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<ErrorKind>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<IntoInnerError<W>>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<JoinError>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<flate2::mem::CompressError>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<flate2::mem::DecompressError>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<getrandom::error::Error>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<httpdate::Error>>
             <std::io::Error as std::convert::From<rand_core::error::Error>>
           and 5 others
   = note: required for `Result<(), std::io::Error>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, rusqlite::Error>>`
```

my code:

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let conn = rusqlite::Connection::open("data.db")?;
    conn.execute(r#"
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
            usid INT,
            name VARCHAR(256),
            pass VARCHAR(512),
            mail VARCHAR(256)
        )
    "#, [])?;
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            .service(_main)
            // ... Multiple Other Services
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: The "try" operator (`?`) uses `From` to convert errors. `rustqlite` doesn't implement the `From` conversion trait for `std::io::Error` (part of `std::io::Result`). You can change the function signature to `Result<(), rustqlite::Error>`.

Comment: It raises an error saying `this type alias takes 1 generic argument but 2 generic arguments were supplied`

Comment: Are you importing `std::io::Result` somewhere?

Comment: Please don't copy plain error messages into the title.

Comment: Either create a new error type combining the various errors which can emerge from a function (typically an enum); or if introspection isn't needed, use a more dynamic error type such as the one in `anyhow` or `eyre`. This is covered in the links above.